# Difference between university/departmental service and extracurricular university service on CV

Tags: united-states, cv, service-activities, extracurricular

I'm a first year assistant professor and the service component of the CV is somewhat unfamiliar territory for me, since my previous jobs never required service. For the last few years, I've followed Karen Kelsky's rules of the academic CV, which distinguishes between "university/departmental service" and "extracurricular university service" as separate CV sections. Thus far, I've listed all of what I consider to be service activities under the former, but now I'm not sure if some of these activities fit better under the latter category, or even if some of these activities merit space on my CV.

Some specific examples of activities I have under the service section include coordinator/organizer roles (curricular development, study abroad, workshop series), committee work, advisor roles (student organizations), and other miscellaneous things like managing/creating content for departmental social media.

To me, all of these activities were/are time-consuming responsibilities that I've considered worth mentioning in my CV, but now I'm a little uncertain if they all belong there (is any of this CV padding?), and if they do - should they be in separate sections? (my thought is perhaps that distinction Dr. Kelsky makes is hierarchical in some way. For instance, is advising a student group not as highly regarded as committee work?).

And a more general question, if it's allowed, are there certain things you just don't list as service? For instance, I know I will be serving as an advisor to majors/minors soon, but that strikes me as something I should leave off my CV because that's something all TT faculty are expected to do.

Comment: "Karen Kelsky's rules of the academic CV, which distinguishes between "university/departmental service" and "extracurricular university service" as separate CV sections." For physics and adjacent fields, this advice is just wrong.  Lump them together or leave them out.  Karen is more right than most people, but not always right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracurricular service is things you do completely outside the university setting. Volunteering at a food bank or such like these days. Tutoring disadvantaged kids.

The other is service given to the university and its students and staff in some way. Being chair of an admissions or hiring committee. Writing a report, or serving on a committee that is trying to make plans for the future.

There is also an overlap area. If you lead an informal campus Judo club or Chess club, just because you want to, you can probably list it either place, but "extracurricular" is more literally true.

They should probably be separated if the instructions separate them. But if they just ask for service without qualification, you could probably combine them.

And the required activities under Teaching and Research are separate, as you suggest.